# Searching for stars with a given surface temperature and an absolute magnitude?

Tags: star, data-analysis

Do you have in mind any database/sites that I can search for stars that matches a given surface temperature and an absolute magnitude?

For example, when I enter `Temperature=9,500K & AbsoluteMagnitude=0.58` then the search engine returns the result `Vega` and some other stars.

Any suggestions are appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Though not much convenient, I found one.

https://github.com/astronexus/HYG-Database

This is a database that contains information of a lot of stars.

I may use excel to use this database and derive any needed results.

Comment: Does this catalogue report a surface temperature? If not, then a useful answer would say how the temperature is going to be obtained.

Comment: @RobJeffries Right,  I think that the from the database I can only find out the color index of the stars/